# How to encourage a balanced solution in ojAlgo ExpressionBasedModel

Tags: linear-programming, ojalgo

I have the following model:

```
        ExpressionsBasedModel model = new ExpressionsBasedModel();

        Variable va = model.addVariable("va")
                .lower(0);

        Variable vb = model.addVariable("vb")
                .lower(0);

        Variable vc = model.addVariable("vc")
                .lower(0);

        Variable vd = model.addVariable("vd")
                .lower(0);

        Variable ve = model.addVariable("ve")
                .lower(0);

        Expression ef = model.addExpression("ef")
                .lower(0);

        Expression eg = model.addExpression("eg")
                .lower(0);

        Expression eh = model.addExpression("eh")
                .lower(-240);

        Expression ei = model.addExpression("ei")
                .lower(0);

        Expression ej = model.addExpression("ej")
                .lower(0);

        Expression ek = model.addExpression("ek")
                .lower(0);

        Expression el = model.addExpression("el")
                .lower(-2000);

        ef.set(va, -50);
        el.set(va, -100);
        eg.set(va, 100);

        eh.set(vb, -30);
        ef.set(vb, 40);
        ej.set(vb, 20);

        ek.set(vc, -30);
        eg.set(vc, -30);
        ei.set(vc, 60);

        ei.set(vd, -30);
        eg.set(vd, -30);
        ek.set(vd, 60);

        ej.set(ve, -40);
        el.set(ve, -40);
        ek.set(ve, 20);

        ei.weight(1);
        ek.weight(1);

        /*
         * These next 2 lines required to get balanced solution.
         * Without them ei = 720 and ek = 0.
         */
//        ek.lower(360);
//        ei.lower(360);

        model.maximise();

        BasicLogger.debug(model);
```

Although `ei` and `ek` are equally weighted, the solution I get is:

```
############################################
0 <= va: 6.4 <= 6.4
0 <= vb: 8 <= 8
0 <= vc: 15.111111 (300)
0 <= vd: 6.222222 (300)
0 <= ve: 4 (200) <= 4
0 <= ef: 0.0
0 <= eg: 0.0
-240 <= eh: -240.0
0 <= ei: 720.0
0 <= ej: 0.0
0 <= ek: -0.0
-2000 <= el: -800.0
############################################
```

`ei == 720, ek == 0`.

I would prefer a solution in which `ei` and `ek` are as balanced as possible, (`ei == 360, ek == 360`). Is there some way of encoding that requirement for "as balanced as possible" as a weighted expression?

In this specific example I have commented out the lower value constraint that actually result in the behavior I want. In real life, the model is dynamic and I may have 5 equally weighted expressions. I won't know the correct values in order to set the lower constraints.

Comment: Maybe try https://math.stackexchange.com for optimisation modelling questions. Both ei and ek are restricted to positive values, then can't you just penalise the difference between those 2 expressions?

Comment: Cannot penalize difference because penalizing, say, `ei - ek` then maximizes `ek`. If you do both they cancel out.

Comment: You can have different weights on different expressions (different orders of magnitude) but doesn't matter now – you found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, I was able to do this by first converting the values represented by `ei` and `ek` into new variables, with the existing expressions `ei` and `ek` constraining the value of the new variables to the value these expressions previously had. Then I added a new variable, weighted it heavily, and constrained it to be less than each of the new variables.

```
        Expression ei = model.addExpression("ei")
                .lower(0);

        Expression ek = model.addExpression("ek")
                .lower(0);
```

became:

```
        Expression ei = model.addExpression("ei")
                .level(0);
        Variable vei = model.addVariable("vei")
                .lower(0);
        ei.set(vei, -1);

        Expression ek = model.addExpression("ek")
                .level(0);
        Variable vek = model.addVariable("vek")
                .lower(0);
        ek.set(vek, -1);
```

Weighting became:

```
        vei.weight(1);
        vek.weight(1);
```

And added balance variable and constraints:

```
        Variable balance = model.addVariable("balance")
                .weight(100);

        model.addExpression("balance constraint for vei")
                .set(vei, 1)
                .set(balance, -1)
                .lower(0);

        model.addExpression("balance constraint for vek")
                .set(vek, 1)
                .set(balance, -1)
                .lower(0);
```

This results in a solution that is as balanced *as possible*:

```
############################################
0 <= va: 6.4 <= 6.4
0 <= vb: 8 <= 8
0 <= vc: 11.111111
0 <= vd: 10.222222
0 <= ve: 4 <= 4
0 <= vei: 360 (1)
0 <= vek: 360 (1)
balance: 360 (100)
0 <= ef: 0.0
0 <= eg: 0.0
-240 <= eh: -240.0
0 <= ei: 0.0 <= 0
0 <= ej: 0.0
0 <= ek: -0.0 <= 0
-2000 <= el: -800.0
0 <= balance constraint for vei: 0.0
0 <= balance constraint for vek: 0.0
############################################
```